# In iOS: Can my app launch another app and get a response/acknowledgement back

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, upi

In iOS, is there anyway i can launch another app to do something and then get a response back saying that it’s done.

For example: My iOS app APP A launches another app APP B (e.g. Google Pay) to make a payment and then after the payment is made, I would like APP A to receive a response/callback/acknowledgement saying its done.

By the way, I'm having zero trouble getting APP A to launch APP B via `UIApplication.Shared.Open(…)`

** In android we use Android Intent to launch APP B and get a response back to APP A using `OnActivityResult(…)`**.

PS: My App is actually built in React Native using NativeModules

Comment: App B would need to open your app using its URL scheme. This typically means App B needs to accept a callback URL as part of its URL scheme

Comment: Thank you, so, App B is typically a third-party app from a large company and I have no control over what they can do.  I can however successfully launch App B from my own App A.

Comment: Zomato uses this same technique, they open `Google Pay`, and once the payment is done they fire a notification on whose tap you can move back to their app.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i want to implement the solution similar to Android Intent in iOS using swift.